# React app stops working when trying to visualize changes in data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web3js

So I'm trying to update real time a balance and deposit (I'm developing a blockchain dapp) so I await the function in componentWillMount, but the website "crashes" (mouse locked) whenever I call this functions here. I'm guessing its not the way it's done, but where do I call it to stay updated real-time?

```
  async componentWillMount() {
    await this.balance()
    await this.viewDeposit()
  }
```

these are the functions, in case they are the problem

```
  //Balance 
  balance = async() => {
    const web3 = window.web3
    const balanceWei = await web3.eth.getBalance(this.state.account)
    const balance = web3.utils.fromWei(await balanceWei, 'ether') + ' ETH'
    this.setState({balance})
  }

  //Deposit
  viewDeposit = async() =>{
    const web3 = window.web3
    const depositWei = await web3.payments_contract.methods.viewFunds.call()
    const depositAmount = web3.utils.fromWei(await depositWei, 'ether') + 'ETH'
    this.setState({depositAmount})
  }
```

edit: the problem is with the viewDeposit function, when deleting it it works fine

Comment: `componentWillMount` is deprecated for all practical purposes. Use `componentDidMount` instead. I don't necessarily think this will fix whatever issue you have though. What do these functions being called do? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Does any of the code in `viewDeposit` depend on anything in or updated from `balance`? I don't see any point in `componentWillMount` being declared `async`.

Comment: @DrewReese I added the functions

Comment: @DrewReese No, viewDeposit has nothing to do with balance function. And I'm declaring componentWillMount async in order to load blockchain data there

Comment: That's what those two utility functions are doing though. Where in `viewDeposit` does the code have issue?

Comment: @DrewReese I've checked and the problem comes when passing the blockchain data to the state, but I've checked the smart contract and is working correctly.

Comment: Are you referring specifically to `depositAmount` and `this.setState({ depositAmount });`? Are there any errors? What is the problem enqueueing the state update, can you tell? What is smart contract?

Comment: @DrewReese yes I was referring to that. I've checked and when calling any function that comes from the blockchain, it freezes the mouse, I gotta debug better, thanks for your time! I'll figure it out I guess..